# Access to the local environment of a function from another function called by the previous one

Tags: python-3.x, local

Let's take a look at this piece of code:

```py
def a():  # N = 0
    string = "pizza"
    # stuff
    res_b = b(string)

def b(string):  # N = 1
    # stuff
    res_c = c(string)
    return res_c

def c(string):  # N = 2
    # stuff
    return thing
```

I have a long file which has basically the same shape than that. I would like to remove the parameter `str` from the definitions and to make b and c able to read it directly (I mean not using an external dictionary) from the N-1 function. So I wonder if a function could read the local environment of the one which called it.

Does anything look like what I am looking for ?

Comment: What does all these functions achieve? `I have a long file which has basically the same shape than that.`, what you mean same shape?

Comment: By 'same shape' I mean I have a main function which calls a secondary one which calls another one, and so long, and all of them have the same parameters. I wonder if each function can access to the locals of the caller one.

Comment: Sure, can you give a concrete example of how you call these functions? also `str` is a python builtin name, not supposed to be used as a variable name

Comment: What those functions do is not the matter I think, it could be any piece of code with a lot of functions calling other ones. It was just a doodle of the piece of code which made me think about the question if it could help understanding how the idea came to me.

Comment: That makes the question abstract, what you want to do with the function can decide how you can refactor the code, Just extend your doodle so that it makes sense and is runnable